# TypeError: this.props.loginActionCreater is not a function in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-middleware

I am new for react redux here I am trying to call two actions in component.
There is login page after click on button I am calling one action that will fetch auth_token then that token I am using in componentWillReceiveProps() for calling another action.below is my code

Issue: While I am click on button its showing an error which I have mentioned in questions title.

UI:

```
<Button
        block
        bsSize="large"
        disabled={!this.validateForm()}
        onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
      >
        Login
      </Button>
```

functionality:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from 'react- 
 bootstrap';
import { loginActionCreater } from '../../actions/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchListOfCandidate } from 
'../../actions/FetchCandidateAction/FetchCandidateAction';

handleSubmit() {
this.props.loginActionCreater(this.state.email, this.state.password);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if (nextProps.token) {
  this.props.fetchListOfCandidate(nextProps.token);
  history.push('/HeaderComponents');
}
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
error: state.login.error,
token: state.login.token
}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
  actions: {
          loginActionCreater: bindActionCreators(loginActionCreater, dispatch),
          fetchListOfCandidate: bindActionCreators(fetchListOfCandidate, dispatch)
         }
 }
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginComponent);
```

If I just dispatch single action its working fine but while dispatching two actions its showing error which mentioned in title.

here is how I am dispatching single action which working fine:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({ loginActionCreater }, dispatch);
 }
```

what I am doing wrong please correct me if someone knows.Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `mapDispatchToProps` method when you have two actions.  Look here:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      loginActionCreater: bindActionCreators(loginActionCreater, dispatch),
      fetchListOfCandidate: bindActionCreators(fetchListOfCandidate, dispatch)
    }
  }
}
```

You are returning an object, with the key `action`.  When you have a single action, your `mapDispatchToProps` looks like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ loginActionCreater }, dispatch);
}
```

Its not returning an object with the key `action`.

If you'd like to keep your implementation of `mapDispatchToProps` with two action.  Please try invoking your action like this:

```
this.props.actions.loginActionCreater()
```

Comment: Thank you @tpdietz for giving fast response and your value able time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mapDispatchToProps` function with an unnecessary parent object, which is `actions`. If you would like to keep this logic, then you need to use your actions like:

```
this.props.actions.loginActionCreater()
```

When you want to use multiple action creators with `bindActionCreators`, you can simply do it like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ loginActionCreater , fetchListOfCandidate }, dispatch)
}
```

With this setup you can use action creators as `this.props.loginActionCreator`.

By the way, actually you don't need `bindActionCreators` or `mapDispatchToProps` at all. If you like there is a shorthand method. Use connect like this:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, { loginActionCreater , fetchListOfCandidate } )(LoginComponent);
```

Comment: Thank you @devserkan for giving fast response and your value able time and also giving more information regarding my question,for me both answer is working. thank you so much